# How to stop the controls from moving the cube with the mouse (gift/page2)

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

(gift/page2)
in this code: https://www.songnes.com/gift/page2.html

you can see a working example of a red cube rotating.
But I want to stop from moving the cube, using the mouse, or the fingers in the iPad.
I want to keep the cube in the same place.
Rotating YES! but not moving in space...

I comment this line

// let controls;

and this one

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

but the code won't work. I would like waht am I doing wrong or how to solve this...
if you want to see the full code see this .txt file: https://www.songnes.com/gift/page2.txt

thank you

P.S. I don't know how to put the code here, yet (any video showing how)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete controls, just add this line :

```
controls.enabled = false;
```